# Where is mysqldbcompare?

Tags: 12.04, mysql

The MySQL docs refer to a utility [mysqldbcompare](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.3/en/mysqldbcompare.html). But it doesn't seem like I have it installed, and when I type `mysqldbcompare` it doesn't suggest any packages (Ubuntu 12.04). Where can I find this utility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since mysql-utilities is not available from the 12.04 repo, you'll have to install the quantal version instead

1. Download this [deb](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mysql-utilities/mysql-utilities_1.0.5-1_all.deb) file
2. Install python-mysql.connector: `sudo apt-get install python-mysql.connector`
3. Run `sudo dpkg -i mysql-utilities_1.0.5-1_all.deb`